# Extract a svg from a URL

Tags: image, svg

I want to extract a svg file from a URL.
The background image URL is inside this text file, copy and paste the code - https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/41f7
Thanks.

Comment: The basic idea is: 1. remove `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,` from the begining. 2. replace all `%3Cs` with `<`, all `%3E` with `>` and all `%23` with `#`

Comment: @exaneta does that site actually allow you to post its contents here as comments?

Comment: @enxaneta thanks for your help. I have made the changes and how I obtain the picture?.